# Get output within multiple date ranges (and if statements) in Power Query

Tags: if-statement, powerquery, date-range

Edited to include full code with the Add Column function in Power Query. The "Removed Columns1" refers to the previous step, and name the custom column as Price.

I'm trying to add a custom column in Power Query to output a price for specific date ranges. Tried the following M code but I get an error instead:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Price", each
    if [Date]<#date(08,12,2019) then "11.50"
    else if [Date]>#date(08,11,2019) and [Date]<#date(10,14,2019) then "0.00"
    else if [Date]>#date(10,13,2019) and [Date]<#date(12,30,2019) then "11.50"
    else "2.50")
```

The error I get back:

> Expression.Error: The Date operation failed because the resulting value falls outside the range of allowed values.

Comment: Should have thought of including the error. I have updated my post above to include the error message.

Comment: Looks like the suggestion below resolved my error. Thanks for looking, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `#date(2019,08,11)` not `#date(8/11/2019)`:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Price", each
    if [Date]<#date(2019,8,12) then "11.50"
    else if [Date]>#date(2019,8,11) and [Date]<#date(2019,10,14) then "0.00"
    else if [Date]>#date(2019,10,13) and [Date]<#date(2019,12,30) then "11.50"
    else "2.50"
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have attempted to replicate the format as suggested, but I get the same error. I've updated my original question to include the full code that came with adding custom column and the error I get.

Comment: Ignore my comment above. Just reattempted from scratch and it worked. Thanks so much!